# data on fragment loss after chang efragment using bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have 5 fragment and shown with bottom navigation bar. Lets call the first fragment is fragment A. I load data from fragment a using volley and display it using recycler view. when i click the bottom navigation to another fragment ( fragment B) and click back fragment A. the data is gone

Main Activity that contain bottom navigation fragment:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext())) {
            bottomNavigationView=(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
            frameLayout=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);

            herbal= new herbal();
            crude = new crude();
            database=new database();
            analysis=new analysis();
            compound=new compound();

            setFragment(herbal);

            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                    {
                        case R.id.nav_herbal:
                            setFragment(herbal);
                            return true;

                        case R.id.nav_crude:
                            setFragment(crude);
                            return true;

                        case R.id.nav_database:
                            setFragment(database);
                            return true;

                        case R.id.nav_analysis:
                            setFragment(analysis);
                            return true;

                        case R.id.nav_compound:
                            setFragment(compound);
                            return true;

                        default:
                            return false;

                    }
                }


            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "internet is not avialable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }

    private boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(netInfos != null)
                if(netInfos.isConnected())
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

and this is the code on recyclerview fragment A:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_herbal, container, false);
        herbalModels = new ArrayList<>();
        kampoModels = new ArrayList<>();

        searchHerbal = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_herbal);
        searchHerbal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchHerb();
            }
        });
        loadData = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadRecyclerView);
        RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        sortData(rootView);
        get20DataJamu();
        get20DataKampo();
        StartRecyclerViewJamu(rootView);


        return rootView;

    }

    private void searchHerb() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        searchHerbs searchHerbs = new searchHerbs();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, searchHerbs);
        ft.commit();
    }


    private void StartRecyclerViewKampo(View rootView) {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_herbal);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        kampoAdapter = new kampoAdapter(mRecyclerView, getActivity(), kampoModels);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(kampoAdapter);
        kampoAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                kampoModels.add(null);
                kampoAdapter.notifyItemInserted(kampoModels.size() - 1);
                handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        kampoModels.remove(kampoModels.size() - 1);
                        kampoAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(kampoModels.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = kampoModels.size();
                        int end = start + 20;
                        loadMoreKampo(start, end);
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadMoreKampo(final int start, final int end) {
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onresponse" + jsonArray.toString());
                        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                kampoModels.add(
                                        new kampoModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("albumId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("thumbnailUrl")
                                        )
                                );
                                kampoAdapter.notifyItemInserted(kampoModels.size());

                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }
                        kampoAdapter.setLoaded();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onerror" + volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

    private void get20DataKampo() {
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onresponsekampo" + jsonArray.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "lengthresponse" + jsonArray.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                kampoModels.add(
                                        new kampoModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("albumId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("thumbnailUrl")
                                        )
                                );

                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onerrorkampo" + volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);

    }


    private void StartRecyclerViewJamu(final View rootView) {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_herbal);
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // create an Object for Adapter
        mAdapter = new herbalAdapter(mRecyclerView, getActivity(), herbalModels);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        loadData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                herbalModels.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(herbalModels.size() - 1);
                handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        herbalModels.remove(herbalModels.size() - 1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(herbalModels.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = herbalModels.size();
                        int end = start + 20;
                        loadMoreJamu(start, end);

                    }
                }, 5000);

            }
        });


    }

    private void get20DataJamu() {

        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onresponse" + jsonArray.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "lengthonresponse" + jsonArray.length());

                        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                herbalModels.add(
                                        new herbalModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("userId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("body")
                                        )
                                );

                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onerror" + volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }


    private void loadMoreJamu(final int start, final int end) {
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onresponse" + jsonArray.toString());
                        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                herbalModels.add(
                                        new herbalModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("userId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("body")
                                        )
                                );
                                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(herbalModels.size());
                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }
                        mAdapter.setLoaded();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onerror" + volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);

    }

    private void sortData(final View rootView) {

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filter_herbal);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        List<categoriesHerbal> itemList = new ArrayList<categoriesHerbal>();
        itemList.add(
                new categoriesHerbal(
                        "1",
                        "Jamu"
                )
        );
        itemList.add(
                new categoriesHerbal(
                        "2",
                        "Kampo"
                )
        );
        ArrayAdapter<categoriesHerbal> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<categoriesHerbal>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, itemList);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    categoriesHerbal selectedValue = (categoriesHerbal) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String categories = (String) selectedValue.getCategories();
                    String idCategories = (String) selectedValue.getIdCategories();
                    StartRecyclerViewJamu(rootView);

                } else {
                    categoriesHerbal selectedValue = (categoriesHerbal) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String categories = (String) selectedValue.getCategories();
                    String idCategories = (String) selectedValue.getIdCategories();
                    StartRecyclerViewKampo(rootView);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your setFragment() to,

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame,fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

and when you want to come back, just remove that last fragment.